# How to set up maven?

Tags: maven, settings, artifactory

How to set up Maven (settings.xml) and Artifactory to access all repositories through Artifactory? 
My current settings are as follows and I even fail to get the Maven-deploy plugin
to execute. The error is that it was not found in any repos (local + artifactory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>repo</name>
      <url>http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/repo</url>
      <id>repo</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

[host]:[port] are real in file and so is [username][password] checked that 3 times.

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\[username]\.m2), repo (http://[host]:[port]/artifactory/repo)] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: `http://host/port/` does not look like proper hostname and port

Comment: it is proper host and port in file, sorry for ambiguity @Lashane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifactory can generate the right `settings.xml` file for you. Look for `Maven Settings` link on the right side menu of the home screen.